# Animation with scan QR code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Emgucv and Zxing to create a QR Code Scanner And I have created a customer PictureBox to scan QR Code.The webcam is responsible for scanning the QR Code to PictureBox.And I also want to make an animation of a scan in PictureBox.The code works fine but the animation of the red line doesn't show up in the PictureBox when I start to scan QR code.Here's my Code:

Customer picturebox:

```
public partial class qrCodeViewer : PictureBox
{
    int y = 0;
    public Timer _timer;

    public qrCodeViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        y += 10;
        if (y >= 300)
        {
            y = 0;
        }
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), new Point(0, y), new Point(360, y));
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

WinForms:

```
private void readQR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    qrRealTime._timer = new Timer();
    qrRealTime._timer.Start();
    qrRealTime._timer.Interval = 50;
    qrRealTime._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(qrRealTime._timer_Tick);
    openWebCam();
    _timer.Start();
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
}

private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(360, 280);
    frame = cap.QueryFrame();
    qrRealTime.Image = frame.ToBitmap();

    ZXing.IBarcodeReader reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();

    ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode(frame.ToBitmap());

    if (result != null)
    {

    }

}
```

My problem is how to show up the animation in PictureBox?
[WinForms's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD7H1.png)

Comment: Would you describe the exact problem you are facing, please? Doesn't the red line show up?

Comment: Is the image shown correctly in the picturebox?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes, it is.But the red line doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call order in the OnPaint method matters.

First call

```
base.OnPaint(pe);
```

to draw the beneath image.

Then call the other two lines to draw the red line. Now the code looks like

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);
    Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), new Point(0, y), new Point(360, y));
}
```

Comment: @RicoChoi reorder the calls should have solved the problem of the red line not showing. What is the problem now?

Comment: I have no idea how to reorder it. base.OnPaint(pe) is in the OnPaint method of customer PictureBox.And the captured image is in the WinForms. How to call the OnPaint method of customers control in the WinForms?Is possible to make an animation in the same PictureBox?

Comment: @RicoChoi by reorder, I mean in the OnPaint method, move the line base.OnPaint to the first line (now it is the last line), that is all need to be modified.  You don't need to call the picture box' OnPaint method from the WinForm, it is triggered when the timer invalidates the picture box.

Comment: I edited it but the red line still doesn't show up.Is the image of camera cover the red line?I have added SendToBack() to PictureBox and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RicoChoi pls upload your project to GitHub so I can take a look at it.

Comment: I don't know how to upload the file to GitHub.May I upload the project to google drive?[QRCodeScanner(Google drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YkEllxYlcIbGpjRlNCY052SE0)

Comment: The problem is that the red line is drawn on the Panel, and still beneath the PictureBox. You can make the animation on the PictureBox. I have a sample downloadable from [Here](https://github.com/kennyzx/MISC/blob/master/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip)

Comment: Finally, it works.Thanks.May I ask another question about the animation of the red line?Whatever I set the _timer.Interval is 30 or 100, the red line moving speed the same.Is possible to make it fast?

Comment: It needs some time to process all these logic: Render the frame in the picture box, show the animation, and read the bar code. I guess it need more than 100 ms to do all these. So even if you make the timer interval a lot smaller like 30ms, they have to wait in a queue, since there is only one CPU processing the queue. Use another background thread to read the barcode, the animation may become faster.

Comment: It's very helpful.Thank you very much.